# System.Windows ContextMenu ItemClick Event?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm making a WPF application, but in my code I need to make a ContextMenu, it seemed really easy:

```
_menu = new ContextMenu();
_menu.Items.Add("My menu item");
```

Then I used it, and everything works like a charm.

However, I need to know when "My menu item" is clicked, but I can't seem to find the right event, I'm searching for something like ItemClick event, but cant't find it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding an item that is clickable rather than just a string.  For example:

```
_menu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.Click += MyClickHandler;
item.Header = "My Menu Item";
_menu.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 3):

I never did it in code, always used XAML.
However, it is something like this:

```
 _menu = new ContextMenu();
 MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();
 mi.Items.Add("My menu item");
 mi.Click += (sender,args) =>
 {
         // Do what you want, or instead of a lambda  
         // you can even add a separate method to the class
 };
 _menu.Items.Add(mi);
```

The only doubt is adding the text to the menu item. You'll have to try as in the example or maybe add a TextBlock to the MenuItem.Items collection

Comment: The MenuItem does not have a Text property. I see in Steve Danner answer that is the Header property. +1 also for him.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
    _menu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
    item.Header = "My menu item";
    item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(item_Click);
    _menu.Items.Add(item);
```