# WPF, get click from dynamically updated ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I've got a context menu that is updated dynamically using the following code

```
        videoMonitor.ContextMenu.ItemsSource = SourceNames;
```

And the WPF:

```
    <Viewbox x:Name="videoMonitor" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,197.333,-0.333" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Image Name="VideoSurface" Source="{Binding VideoBitmap, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Viewbox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Viewbox.ContextMenu>
        </Viewbox>
```

It works fine and updates as it should, but how can I receive click events from each item in the list? I know how I would do it with a statically created ContextMenu, but not with one updated using ItemsSource.

Best,

Joe

Comment: Use MVVM and commands; have the context menu bound to objects that include the correct command objects already

Comment: Not very advanced solution, but is an option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651977/system-windows-contextmenu-itemclick-event

Comment: @BradleyDotNET any example code squire?